# Getting value in jQuery from Boostrap 3 select

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Boostrap 3 and want to AJAX post a form created with Boostrap 3, but am having issues in obtaining the value of my  drop down menu within a modal.

Generated HTML

```
<div class="modal in" id="UploadCsv" tabindex="-1">
    ...
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-4 control-label" for supplier Sku">SKU</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <select class="form-control" name="supplierSku" id="supplierSku>
                 <option value="1">Name</option>
                 <option value="2">Form</option>
                  ...
             <select class="form-control" name="form" id="form>
                 <option value="1">Name</option>
                 <option value="2">Form</option>
                 ...
```

JS

```
$('input, select'). $('#UploadCsv')).each(function() {
    data[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).attr('value');
});
```

If I look at data in the console I have

```
supplierSku: undefined
form: undefined
```

despite selecting the option from the drop down. Jquery is picking up the name of the form group, but not teh value.

Based on my selection I would have expected to see supplierSku: 1 etc. Any suggestions on how to pick up the value for the selected drop down in jquery?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you forgot the closing quotes for both select id's:

```
<div class="modal in" id="UploadCsv" tabindex="-1">
    ...
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-4 control-label" for supplier Sku">SKU</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">

            // Closing quotes on id attribute
            <select class="form-control" name="supplierSku" id="supplierSku">
                 <option value="1">Name</option>
                 <option value="2">Form</option>
                  ...

            // Closing quotes on id attribute
             <select class="form-control" name="form" id="form">
                 <option value="1">Name</option>
                 <option value="2">Form</option>
                 ...
```